# How do I compare with a string in ng-class?

Tags: angularjs, ng-class

This line doesn't seem to work for me.

```
Sort By: <a href="" ng-click="setOrder('title')" ng-class="{active: orderProp == 'title'}">Alphabetical</a>
```

Do I have to escape 'title' in orderProp == 'title' somehow?

in the controller I have

```
...
$scope.orderProp = 'title';
$scope.setOrder = function(sortBy){
            $scope.orderProp = sortBy;
}
...
```

Thank you

**Update:** ***Using v1.3.0-beta.17***

Adding  `ng-class="{active:orderProp=='pagetitle'}` to

```
<a href="" ng-click="setOrder('pagetitle')" ng-class="{active:orderProp=='pagetitle'}">Alphabetical</a>
```

throws an error

```
"Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.17/$parse/syntax?p0=undefined&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=null&p3=%7Bactive%3AorderProp%3D%3D&p4=%7Bactive%3AorderProp%3D%3D
```

Sorry for the way I present the error but I just started angular last week and don't know a better way

**Update 2:**
error seems to be coming from = == ===. I tried > and no error occured. Is there an alternative syntax to like eq?

**Update 3 with solve**

I mapped each string to an int pagetile->1 code->2 + data-ng-class="{active:orderPropIdx==1};"
Inside the controller I just do if pagetitle set active:orderPropIdx to 1 and so on

Maybe this is a bug in angular 1.3

Comment: not sure it is I get some weird html in the console and I don't see any class attribute

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Will try, until then maybe you have the time to read the update. Thx

Comment: Can't reproduce your error, really.

Comment: have u tried single quoting `'active'`?

Comment: I get a parse error with 'active' "Error: [$parse:ueoe] errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.17/$parse/ueoe?p0=%7B

Comment: Could you please post a fiddle? You're update isn't really clear on what you're doing.

Answer (score 9):

As is stated in the comments, your class name should be surrounded by single quotes.

`ng-class="{'active': orderProp == 'title'}">`

This comparison is case sensitive.

Answer (score 5):

Had the same issue when using ng-class. It refused to dynamically compute the class attribute even though the expression was successfully calculated.

And here is the workaround I've used for the ng-class statement:

```
Sort By: <a href="" ng-click="setOrder('title')" class="{{orderProp == 'title' ? 'active' : ''}}">Alphabetical</a>
```

instead of `ng-class="{active: orderProp == 'title'}` I've switched to `class="{{orderProp == 'title' ? 'active' : ''}}"`

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing. @Dan i'm on 1.3.5 and i'm seeing that the expression evaluates correctly, but the ngClass is not applying the classes.

Comment: That is why I gave the workaround :). Please vote if it helped

Answer (score 1):

[image]
I resolve in this way; 'ClassName':'{{Value}}'=='StringtoCompare', ...

```
ng-class="{ 'btn-danger' : '{{datasource.difficoltaRicetta}}'=='Difficile', 'btn-warning' :'{{datasource.difficoltaRicetta}}'=='Intermedia', 'btn-success' : '{{datasource.difficoltaRicetta}}'=='Facile'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I mapped each string to an int pagetile->1 code->2 + data-ng-class="{active:orderPropIdx==1};" Inside the controller I just do if pagetitle set active:orderPropIdx to 1 and so on

Maybe this is a bug in angular 1.3

Answer (score 0):

This is for people coming to this answer looking for the solution with `[ngClass]`.

```
<a [ngClass]="{ active: selectedValue === 'foo bar' }"> FooBar </a>
```

This would result in adding `class="active"` to the anchor element when the variable `selectedValue` is given the value `"foo bar"`.

Answer (score -3):

The syntax for ng-class can be quite confusing sometimes. Try this.

```
ng-class="{true: 'active', false: ''}[orderProp === 'title']"
```

Include square brackets after the curly braces. Inside the square brackets, you can declare any expression, and declare your results (true/false) and the corresponding classes you want to apply (active).  And be sure to use '===' in your expressions, signifying you want orderProp to be *exactly equal* to what you are comparing it against.

Comment: not working for me. I get Error: [$parse:syntax] angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.17/$parse/syntax?p0=undefined&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=null&p3=%7Btrue%3A&p4=%7Btrue%3A

Comment: Not working for me, either. This is definitely not the solution.